# Calculate deviation after groupby - loop of ufunc does not support argument 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data about electric cars in USA and I am trying to calculate standard deviation for each state. I already calculated mean in that way:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/AlbertKozera/6396b4333d1a9222193e11401069ed9a/raw/ab8733a2135bcf61999bbcac4f92e0de5fd56794/Pojazdy%2520elektryczne%2520w%2520USA.csv')
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
df['range'] = pd.to_numeric(df['range'])
.
.
.
df_avg_range = df.drop(columns = ['state', 'brand', 'model', 'year of production', 'type']).groupby('code', as_index=False)['range'].mean()
```

And here is my return after that:

```
   code       range
0    AK  154.553600
1    AL  156.959936
2    AR  153.950400
3    AZ  152.756000
4    CA  152.359200
5    CO  159.084800
6    CT  155.212000
7    DE  156.322400
8    FL  153.728000
9    GA  154.748800
10   HI  154.503200
11   IA  155.746400
12   ID  157.851200
13   IL  155.200800
14   IN  153.338400
15   KS  154.240000
16   KY  154.162400
17   LA  156.728800
18   MA  134.643200
19   MD  137.080800
20   ME  142.263200
21   MI  132.828000
22   MN  135.828000
23   MO  138.376000
24   MS  132.704000
25   MT  132.552000
26   NC  133.800000
27   ND  136.096800
28   NE  137.150400
29   NH  131.498400
30   NJ  137.760800
31   NM  133.325600
32   NV  137.522400
33   NY  137.476000
34   OH  137.784800
35   OK  134.277600
36   OR  134.504000
37   PA  141.052000
38   RI  137.572000
39   SC  143.348000
40   SD  141.189600
41   TN  139.981600
42   TX  139.233600
43   UT  138.615200
44   VA  141.334400
45   VT  143.104000
46   WA  137.880800
47   WI  143.916800
48   WV  141.008000
49   WY  147.109600
```

Now I am trying to calculate deviation in the same way:

```
df_dev_range = df.drop(columns = ['state', 'brand', 'model', 'year of production', 'type']).groupby('code', as_index=False)['range'].std()
```

And here is my error after that:

```
*** TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type str which has no callable sqrt method
```

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me (pandas 1.1.0, python 3.8.2)

Comment: This os because you dont have the same dtype as him... you should change dtype of range to int or float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `as_index=False` from `groupby`. Standard deviation will be applied to all columns including `groupby` column when keeping `as_index` as `False`.

In order to retain index 0-49 try using the below syntax

`df_dev_range = df.drop(columns = ['state', 'brand', 'model', 'year of production', 'type']).groupby('code',as_index=False).agg({'range':'std'})`

Comment: Im not sure that is true at all, and it is clearly doesnt seem like the issue

Comment: Remove as_index works but without `as_index=False` I dont have iteration 0-49 which I needed.